# Xamarin.Forms PlatformParametwer does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Tags: xamarin, adal, .net-standard-2.0

I am doing a mobile app using ADAL for authentication. I am using VS 2017 Xamarmin.Forms and trageting .Net standard 2.0 for the project. But got the error for the following code. I did some research than found out that PlatformParameters constructor is not supported by .NetCore since .NetCore does not support UI yet. But .Net Standard should support. Is there any solution or workaround? Thank you in advance.

```
 authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientID, new Uri(clientReturnUri), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, this));
```

Comment: `.NetCore`,`.NetStandard` you are all over the place what project have to made my friend are you using `.Net` Framework or `.Net`Core?

Comment: I am developing a Xamarin.Forms project using .Net Standard 2.0.

Comment: A xamarin forms project using .Net Framework or Core?

Comment: Neither .Net Framework nor .Net Core, it's actually using .Net Standard 2.0.

Comment: Not understand which `PlatformParameters`.What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to use Azure Active Directory Authentication libaray (ADAL) to handle the login for a Xamarin Form App.

Comment: @Burtsun9 Okey,do you need 2 arguments in `AcquireTokenAsync` methods ?

Comment: Error code is for PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, this) method. I did some research, it seems for .net standard,PlatformParameters has no constructor with arguments but for .net 4.X it does. In VS2017, Xamarin Forms is targeting .net Standard(in VS2015, it's still .NET, there are many tutorial for VS2015 Xamarin PCL project).The code I use&posted here is from some VS2015 Xamarin PCL sample. I am wondering if there's any solution or workaround.How can I implement the Azure Active Directory authentication for Xamarin Forms with VS2017.I know its confusing hopefully I made myself clear.

Comment: @Burtsun9 You may need to try the implementation that uses `DependencyServices` instead: https://blog.xamarin.com/put-adal-xamarin-forms/